# How do I include the .prisma folder in my sveltekit app production build?

Tags: svelte, prisma, sveltekit

I am using prisma in my sveltekit app. When I build the app none of the modules are included. When deploying the app I copy the package.json and package-lock.json and then run the command `npm ci --omit dev` as stated [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node) which pull the dependencies needed, but the prisma generated files are saved in the adapter-node folder in my project and are obviously not going to be generated when pulling the dependencies. There may be a best practice on the proper way to do this, my thought was to include this folder when I build the app so I don't have to copy my files from the dev project to the build. Is there a way that I can make this folder and its contents be included in the build or a best practice for this?

Comment: Can you take a look at this [article](https://dockyard.com/blog/2022/05/02/sveltekit-with-prisma-on-heroku-oh-my-part-2) for deploying to production?